# How to get a list of characters that lying after a specific key from a String?

Tags: python, string

For Example I need each char after '!' in my String ("192.168.!A.!B")
I want a list contains A and B 
The String maybe like this "Interface Vlan !A , Name !B"

Comment: It would be nice to share your current code snippet

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! There are too many ways to approach this problem. The answers would just turn into a straw-poll for which one people liked. The best thing is to do some research on the topic yourself, find two or three, _analyze_ them, determine if they work for you or not, and _try them out_. Come to us when you have a specific question about something you have attempted to do.

Comment: Thank you, I test the deleted answer and it works, I tried to thank him but it was deleted :/

Comment: Thank you for your advise @PatrickArtner but I tried all methods I know and I search here for someone asked the same or close but I didn't found.
My tests failed so there is no need to publish what I test because they failed.
Besides, I explained the problem I don't think that there is something ambiguous.
Thank you for your greetings :)

Comment: You are wrong. Showing what you tried shows us that you 1) are not simply fishing for a solution 2) let's us guess whatyour skill ´-level is and provide a suitable solution 3) proves you are not actually offloading your work here. 4) brings _you_ the most, because you learn with each of your tries.  And lastely it shows you follow [ask] 's 0th rule: research.

Comment: This is my first question, thank you for your advise I don't know the right ways to publish a question.
I'm sorry to give you bad impression but in fact I have no time to test more so I asked here.
@PatrickArtner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do it with a regular expression:

```
import re

pattern = r"!(.)"
search_string = "192.168.!A.!B"

results = re.findall(pattern, search_string)
# Returns ['A', 'B']
```

This also returns an empty list if the `!` happens at the end of the string.

regex101 is a good place to learn regular expressions and test them out on strings: https://regex101.com/r/lZClzT/1

Answer (score 0):

Try using `split` with list comprehension:

```
print([next(iter(i),None) for i in string.split('!')])
```

Or in a `map`-style way:

```
print(list(map(lambda i: next(iter(i),None),string.split('!'))))
```

Comment: it didn't work with this String:

Command = "Interface Vlan !A, ip address 192.168.1.!B \nName !C \nExit"

Answer (score -1):

This is the answer by someone delete his answer.

a= re.findall('!(\w)',"192.168.!A.!B")
print(a)

Comment: Did you understand or just copy and paste this solution? You could as well have used `[x.strip(".") for x in "192.168.!A.!B".split("!")[1:]]` ... no need for regex at all .. or a simple for loop goig throug the string characterwise - wait for a ! and store the next character in a result list, or ..., or ..., or ...

Comment: Yes I do understand.
but I didn't try your first suggestion because I have a file with commands for a Cisco switch or router so the case may be like this "Interface Vlan !A".
So here there is no "." to use for striping.
Again, thank you for your advice I appreciate that you want me to be better.@PatrickArtner